# Why save_post_$(custom_post_type) is fired even if I am not already saving a post?

Tags: save-post, nonce

I'm registering a custom post type named Datasheet. When registering it, I register the callback for meta boxes

```
'register_meta_box_cb'  => [ $this, "add_metaboxes" ]
```

This is my callback

```
function add_metaboxes ( $post ) {  
   wp_nonce_field ( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'datasheet_meta_nonce');
   add_meta_box( 
   .......
```

Also I registered this hook

```
add_action ('save_post_datasheet', [ $this, 'save_datasheet_meta' ], 10, 2);
```

This is the callback

```
function save_datasheet_meta ( $post_id, $post ) {

    $nonce = wp_verify_nonce ( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'datasheet_meta_nonce');

    if (!$nonce) {
      die ("Security check failed");
    }
```

**Expected/dsidered:** I was expecting that this last callback is fired *when creating and or updating* but *ONLY IN THESE CASES*; so I can check the nonces.

**Actual behaviour** If I simply start to create a new Datasheet, I got nothing else than

```
Security check failed
```

This happens simply opening `domain.tld/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=datasheet` from side admin menu

So I cannot understand WHY this action is fired just entering the page... causing my nonce check to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you choose "Your CPT > Add New", WP calls [get_default_post_to_edit()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_default_post_to_edit/), which actually creates an "empty" post (with `'post_status' => 'auto-draft'`) and then calls [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/).  This is what is causing your `save_datasheet_meta()` function to be called before you think it should.

Hence, generally you should add some additional sanity checks to the beginning of any func you hook into `save_post`, ala:

```
function
save_datasheet_meta ($post_id, $post)
{
    if ('auto-draft' == $post->post_status) {
        // bail, because your nonce will not be set at this point
        return ;
        }

    // post{,-new}.php enqueue some JS which periodically saves the post_content,
    // but NOT any post_meta
    // so, a `save_post` hook func that only cares about updating post_meta should
    // bail when DOING_AUTOSAVE is true
    if (defined ('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return ;
        }

    $nonce = wp_verify_nonce ( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'datasheet_meta_nonce');

    if (!$nonce) {
        die ("Security check failed");
        }

    // save post_meta's here

    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not have a nonce in your metabox, and obviously not check for it in your save handler.

I know everybody copied the codex page on creating metaboxes but the use of nonce there is just super wrong. Nonce is done and validated on the whole submitted form and there is no additional security, or other value by adding it into metabox.

The only thing that the nonce do, is to validate that the submission is from the page edit and not from the quick edit, xml-rpc, or json api, but for that kind of usage you better use a simple hidden input (this might be required if your metabox contains only checkboxes).